# Convert text number to value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have following values from Cell A17:A29

```
Col A      ColH   ColI
02494/1    191    191  Average  
02585/3    77     77   Average
02341/1    22     131 (Average for same ID in ColA)
02341/1    218
```

I need to average the values in Col H based on same IDs in Col A and put the average value in Col I. Since the Col A IDs are string I'm not getting error #N/A in Col I. Following are my code first try to convert IDs to values.

```
    Sub conver()
    Range("A17:A20").Select
    With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
    End With
    End Sub
```

Then

```
    Sub averag()
    With Worksheets("averages")
Range("I17:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=   IF(A17<>A16,AVERAGEIF(A17:INDEX($A17:INDEX(A16:A55,MATCH(1E+99,A16:A55)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A17:INDEX(A16:A55,MATCH(1E+99,A16:A55)+1)<>A17,)),0)),A17,H17:INDEX($H17:INDEX(H17:H55,MATCH(1E+99,A16:A55)+1),MATCH(TRUE ,(INDEX($A17:INDEX(A16:A55,MATCH(1E+99,A16:A55)+1)<>A17,)),0))),"""")"
    End With

    End Sub
```

But it is not working yet. can someone help on this.or has other way to do it. I can't change the IDs format. Thank you.

Comment: Does `0249/1` mean you have `0249` in one cell or that you want to divide 0249 by 1?

Comment: Does copy and paste special values only doesn't help ?

Comment: @ Scott actually it is a ID '02494/1" not 249 divided by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited**: added solution for "unlimited" range

no need for any column A values conversion

if your relevant range lays between rows 17 and 29 of worksheet "averages", then simply go like this:

```
Sub averag()
     Worksheets("averages").Range("A17:A29").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R17C1:RC1,RC1)>1,"""",AVERAGEIF(R17C1:R29C1,RC1,R17C8:R29C8))"
end sub
```

moreover should the lower side of the range be dynamic(i.e., not limited to row 29), then you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub averag()
Dim IDRng As Range

With Worksheets("averages")
    Set IDRng = .Range("A17:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    IDRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R17C1:RC1,RC1)>1,"""",AVERAGEIF(" & IDRng.Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",RC1," & IDRng.Offset(, 7).Address(, , xlR1C1) & "))"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi When i use the code, it gives the same vales from "Col H" to "Col I" no average values?

Comment: I tested code as per your data and it worked. 1) which code version are you actually using: the "static" or the "dynamic"? 2) what are you're data like? are they constants or the result of formulas? you may post data which give that behavior

Comment: Hi, Yes it is working well, may be I had done wrong formatting in col A.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Function SplitSum(r As Range) As Double
Dim i As Integer, X
X = Split(r.Value, "/")
For i = LBound(X) To UBound(X)
    SplitSum = SplitSum + X(i)
Next i
End Function  then use Sub ss()
Worksheets("check").Range("B17").Formula = "=SplitSum(A17)"
Range("B17").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B17:B20")
End Sub
Thanks

Comment: fine that you made it. anyhow if my answer actually resolved your question you may mark it as accepted. if it proved useful you may want to up-vote it. thank you